# How do you parse JSON object keys as integers with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, classcastexception, coercion

I am deserializing a JSON into a `Map<Integer, String>`.

But I am getting the above classCastException if I try to assign a `key` to primitive `int` .

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader(Map.class);
String patternMetadata = "{\"1\":\"name\", \"2\":\"phone\", \"3\":\"query\"}";
Map<Integer, String> map = reader.readValue(patternMetadata);
System.out.println("map: " + map);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("map: " + entry.getKey());
        int index = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("map**: " + index);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting this `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` exception on second line in `try` block.

I even tried changing `int index = enty.getKey().intValue()`. But still the same exception occurs.

P.S.: I am running it in an Android studio using Robolectric framework.

Comment: JSON properties are *never* `int` values; they're *always* strings. I suspect you should just parse the string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those keys aren't integers, they're strings. Note the quotes on them:

```
String patternMetadata = "{\"1\":\"name\", \"2\":\"phone\", \"3\":\"query\"}";
// ------------------------^^-^^-----------^^-^^------------^^-^^
```

If this is JSON (it seems to be), object property names are *always* strings.

You'll need a `Map<String, String>` and then you'll need to parse the keys to `int` explicitly (if needed).

Comment: But then how does it get successfully deserialized into a Map<Integer, String> ?

Comment: @Heisenberg: It doesn't, it gets deserialized into `Map`. Remember type erasure. :-) `ObjectMapper` is just using a raw `Map`. The second line of your `try` block is the first place in your code that the compiler inserted the type-specific cast, which is why it fails there.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson can deserialize keys into some default types (or custom types with some extra configuration) if you tell it to.

Since `Map` is a generic type, you'll need to use a [`TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to describe the parameterization you want.

[`reader`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#reader-java.lang.Class-) is deprecated since 2.5. You should use [`readerFor`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerFor-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) instead. Construct your `ObjectReader` by providing an appropriate `TypeReference` with `Integer` keys for the `Map`. Jackson will then know you expect `Integer` values as the keys to your map.

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<Map<Integer, String>>() {
});
```

Full example

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<Map<Integer, String>>() {
});
String patternMetadata = "{\"1\":\"name\", \"2\":\"phone\", \"3\":\"query\"}";
Map<Integer, String> map = reader.readValue(patternMetadata);
System.out.println("map: " + map);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    try {
        System.out.println("map: " + entry.getKey());
        int index = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println("map**: " + index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

prints

```
map: {1=name, 2=phone, 3=query}
map: 1
map**: 1
map: 2
map**: 2
map: 3
map**: 3
```